# Create a list of Tuples using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have some data files:

```
data1.txt:
SchoolAdress1
Surname1;10
Surname2;7

data2.txt:
SchoolAdress2
Surname3;9
Surname4;6

data3.txt:
SchoolAdress3
Surname5;10
Surname6;6
```

And create the following class:

```
class Pupil
{
public string Surname {get; set;}
public int Grade {get; set;}

...
}
```

My collection is:

```
List<Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>> data;
```

Item1 of Tuple is school adress.

I need to create a new list using LINQ `List<Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>> results`where all pupils grades are 10.

Final result should be like this:

```
results[0]:
SchoolAdress1
Surname1;10

results[1]:
SchoolAdress3
Surname5;10
```

My problem is that I have to create a new Tuple `Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>` . I tried this: `var results = data.Select(list => list.Item2.Where(pupil => pupil.Grade == 10).ToList()).ToList();`

Comment: And what problems are you having performing that operation?

Comment: What have you tried? You added a tag of linq so please show some query you tried

Comment: Please add something that you have tried

Comment: You class does not have the School Address so how do you expect the get the address in the output?

Comment: Why a `List` of `Tuple` instead of using `GroupBy`? So simply use `data.Where(x => x.Group == 10).GroupBy(x => x.SchoolAdress);`

Comment: @jdweng my class shouldn't have school adress, I get it during data reading from text files.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question and not in the comments :) easier for other readers

Comment: Also what is the problem with your attempt? In what way it doesn't return what you would want?

Comment: You need extract the school address from text files and associate the address with the pupils if you expect to put address in output.

Comment: @jdweng "My collection is..."  says that `data` is already in the same format as the desired answer.

Comment: You are making it too dificult. Create more objects instead of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your `Tuple` approach you can make the following:

```
var filteredData = data.Select(x => new Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>(x.Item1, x.Item2.Where(y => y.Grade == 10).ToList())).ToList();
```

`filteredData` is now a `List<Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>` where the `Item2` part of the `Tuple` got filtered by `Grade == 10`.

If you would like to remove all entries with `0` entries in the `List<Pupil>` of the `Tuple` you could call this:

```
filteredData.RemoveAll(x => !x.Item2.Any());
```

Or include a `Where` clause to the first line and change it to this:

```
var filteredData = data.Select(x => new Tuple<string, List<Pupil>>(x.Item1, x.Item2.Where(y => y.Grade == 10).ToList()))
                   .Where(x => x.Item2.Any())
                   .ToList();
```

Here you can see it in action:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BeeNVv